# How to add force to an actor in unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am using blueprints. I have an actor that I want to move using a physics force/impulse when they are spawned. Basically I want to push the actor when they are spawned. I have physics and gravity enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the add impulse, or add force nodes.

[image]

Add impulse is designed to be used only once to add a burst at a location.
E.g hitting a golf ball.
Add force is designed to be used multiple times to gradually move objects.
E.g Player pushing a heavy cube

Use whichever is best suited for your needs.